# What's wrong in that multithread method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote a method that should find anagrams in given glossary. I suppose there is a mistake in synchronization somewhere.
I'm also will be glad for notations about code style or how to optimize some parts (especially with description what i'm doing wrong).
I'm newbie in Java so please describe as clear as you can :)

```
public class Anagram {
    Map<String, HashSet<String>> anagrams = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>());
    List<String> glossary;
    AtomicInteger availableProcessors = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger start = new AtomicInteger();
    AtomicInteger end = new AtomicInterger();  // the end of current part

Anagram(Glossary glossary) {
    this.glossary = new ArrayList<>(glossary.getGlossary());
}

public void findAnagrams() {
    availableProcessors.set(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    end.set(0);
    start.set(0);
    buildAnagramMap();
    // displayAnagrams();   // not used in this part of code
}

/**
 * Builds map of anagrams
 */
private void buildAnagramMap() {
    System.out.println("Starting build anagrams map at thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    if (glossary != null) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < availableProcessors.get(); i++) {
            executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.err.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " started");
                    end.set(start.get() + glossary.size() / availableProcessors.get());
                    // if not divisible by number of available processors then we add residue to last thread
                    if ((glossary.size() % availableProcessors.get() > 0) &&
                            ((glossary.size() - end.get()) < (glossary.size() / availableProcessors.get()))) {
                        end.set(glossary.size());
                    }
                    for (int i = start.get(); i < end.get(); i++) {
                        String key = sortString(glossary.get(i));
                        HashSet<String> val = anagrams.get(key);
                        if (val == null) {
                            val = new HashSet<>();
                            anagrams.put(key, val);
                        }
                        val.add(glossary.get(i));
                        start.set(start.get() + 1);
                    }
                    System.err.println("Completed thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        while (!executorService.isTerminated()) {
            try {
                executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Glossary doesn't exist");
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " successfully ended");
}
```

Part of output:

1. backward backward // wrong
2. радистка // wrong
3. стопит // wrong
4. роста сорта // OK
5. бутылочек бутылочке // OK
6. Будет Будте  // OK
7. трапу парту // OK
8. посолил  // wrong
9. course source // OK

Comment: You will be better off giving an explanation as to how it went wrong and any log files and exception stacktraces along with your code.

Comment: Just a question. Is there really the need for AtomicIntegers? I thought, those AtomicFamily is mainly for "pass-reference-similar" stuff.

Comment: where do you start your threads? I don't see a call to start them ,and a call to join them

Comment: @Quantico I do it with ExecutorService: ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
Then just execute(new Runnable(){...});

Comment: @icbytes I'm not sure about that, but I'm using it every time when my variables can be modified in threads.

Comment: @Toisen you should probably read up on the Atomic* classes before coming here. Programming isn't magic nor is it based on simple recipes. You have to understand something to use it correctly.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I don't see any disadvantages in using Atomic. I know the main goal of Atomics. I just using it if I'm not sure if my variable should be locked. If I think that mine methods can be in trouble because of chaotically changeable variable then I just make that variable Atomic. Maybe it's a bad decision but I should to know why before I will deny it. For now I don't know any reasons for not to use that little trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems was not only in threads but in algorithm too: start.set(start.get() + 1);
Should be start.set(end.get() + 1);
The next thing is that I should set new value to for field start in the beginning and save initial value in thread-local variable.

```
/**
 * Builds map of anagrams
 */
private void buildAnagramMap() {
    System.out.println("Starting build anagrams map at thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    if (glossary != null) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < availableProcessors.get(); i++) {
            executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    end.set(start.get() + glossary.size() / availableProcessors.get());
                    int startAt = start.get();
                    start.set(end.get() + 1);
                    // if not divisible by number of available processors then we add residue to last thread
                    if ((glossary.size() % availableProcessors.get() > 0) &&
                            ((glossary.size() - end.get()) < (glossary.size() / availableProcessors.get()))) {
                        end.set(glossary.size());
                    }
                    for (int i = startAt; i < end.get(); i++) {
                        String key = sortString(glossary.get(i));
                        HashSet<String> val = anagrams.get(key);
                        if (val == null) {
                            val = new HashSet<>();
                            anagrams.put(key, val);
                        }
                        val.add(glossary.get(i));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        while (!executorService.isTerminated()) {
            try {
                executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Glossary doesn't exist");
    }
}
/**
 * Splits glossary on fragments to search
 * @return point to start
 */
private synchronized int fragmentation() {
    end.set(start.get() + glossary.size() / availableProcessors.get());
    int startAt = start.get();
    start.set(end.get() + 1);
    return startAt;
}
```

Comment: To keep changes of variables threadsafe, one usually should not mix the meaning of atomic in computer science and the java namespace. Common error. The proper threadsafety-approaches mostly involve to use some stuff from the concurrent namespace.  Another common technique is the keyword synchronized { }, where the stub is guaranteed to be executed threadsafe.

Comment: @icbytes imo ReentrantLock much flexible than synchronized. synchronized always wait until end of operation if resource locked when ReentrantLock allow you to do something (e.g with tryLock()).

Comment: If there are really cases where performance is increased by ReentrantLock compared  to synchronized and we are still threadsafe, then I would also switch. Do You know situations ?

Comment: @icbytes I suppose you should read articles from JavaOne conference of 2011. There was pretty clear arguments and benchmarks about performance of synchronized and non-fair ReentrantLock. In short synchronized is slightly better with low number of threads (<4) and low concurrency when ReentrantLock can give you advantage when you lock resources pretty often. There is a screen of a benchmark http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-VVlWLZtFbLs/TtKXAF_k5cI/AAAAAAAAAyk/xaqPkbHlzyg/s640/concurrency_performance.png